# How to Bypass SSL check in iOS 11 using Ionic Cordova framework and self signed certificate

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ssl-certificate, self-signed

In my app I need to call some REST API service calls. The certificate on the target development server where REST API services are deployed is self signed. So when I am running app I am getting error like:

Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “192.168.10.20:8080” invalid.....which could put your confidential information at risk.

As this server is only for dev/testing purpose so I simply wants to ignore ssl check ... How can I achieve it? I tried following way:
 [AppDelegate.m file] but didn't succeeded as below code is not working in iOS 11 ...

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

I am using ionic 3 & Cordova 7 in my app.

Comment: Unfortunately "allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost" does not works anymore in iOS 11 for cordova (WKWebView).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, I am just researching the same problem. Looks like in iOS 11 things are a bit more restricted. I am answering here for WKWebView.

In essence you need to do:

- place custom auth code to the WKWebView plugin code
- load resource directly from Cordova (then WKWebView events gets properly triggered)
- disable ATS (NSAppTransportSecurity)

**Detail description**

What you should do in detail is the following (if you are using WKWebView):

You need to modify CDVWKWebViewEngine.m (plugin code). You need to add there:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge 
*)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)
(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition 
disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler {
    SecTrustRef serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, 
    [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:serverTrust]);
}
```

However, please note - this only works when WKWebView is initialized (i.e. loaded via cordova framework).

So **you need to load your application also from that URI where API is**. I presume you have local network (self signed certificate), so this should not be a problem. If you will load application locally (i.e. from index.html) then this wont work!

Additionally you need to disable iOS ATS in application *.plist setting file like:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

This is what works for me.

Additional resources:

- Very nice testing site for different SSL scenarios (including self signed): https://badssl.com/
- Apple forum discussion on this topic: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/269452#269452

*Disclamer: Disabling certificate check should be avoided, use this only if you have a very good reason or other restrictions. You still have communication security, but you have no trust. Hence men in the middle attack is possible! If you decide to go with this option, you should also use certificate pinning to make things more secure.*

Comment: @Peter..can you share complete CDVWKWebViewEngine.m file with me..I have integrated this code in mine but didn't succeeded..

Comment: @KamleshKumar: Of course I can share, here it is: https://gist.github.com/PeterStegnar/63cb8c9a39a13265c3a855e24a33ca37

Comment: @PeterStegnar didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge method is not getting called in my ionic 4 app

Comment: It is called only when view is initialised. So then you first time use or redirect/reload it.

Comment: @PeterStegnar, Will this change can go for production deployment?

Comment: @r1webs: As goes per Apple restrictions, yes. However, I would highly discourage you from putting this to the production. This should be used for testing purposes only.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @peter I have found one more workaround for checking app in ios11 for testing purpose whether API's are getting hit properly or not. You can forcefully change the webview from WKWebView  to UIWebview by adding below tag in config.xml

```
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" />
```

now add following code in Appdelegate.m file

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

it worked for me..!

Note:only for dev/testing purpose.not recommended for production deployments

Comment: The problem of this workaround is that you are using kinda deprecated web view for iOS. Apple recommends to use WKWebView: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview. There are a lot of reasons for this (one for example, you have a touch delay, which is really bad user experience). The question is if you can afford this with your users?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a problem associated with an invalid SSL certificate on a server.

In my application, I am using the WKWebView plugin, which has become a requirement to send applications to an App Store. It is in this plug-in that an adjustment needs to be made to ignore invalid SSL certificates, in the file "plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/src/ios/CDVWKWebViewEngine.m", includes:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler {

    NSLog(@"Allow all");

    SecTrustRef serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    CFDataRef exceptions = SecTrustCopyExceptions (serverTrust);

    SecTrustSetExceptions (serverTrust, exceptions);
    CFRelease (exceptions);
    completionHandler (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:serverTrust]);

}
```

As a result, the application will not take into account invalid SSL certificates.

References of https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/15610

Remembering that it is not recommended to do this in applications in production, because invalid SSL certificates can compromise the security of the application.